# Angularstrap dropdown closing when clicking outside

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-strap

Is there anyway of only closing an angularstrap dropdown when you click outside only.
The default behavior is such as if you click in the dropdown it closes it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
 $('#dropDown li').click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
```

Comment: Indeed it works !
But it also prevents my a links inside the dropdown to work ...

Comment: you can make it prevent only specific fields. e,g $('#dropDown li input').click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });